# Start WPF app after MSI installation complete

Tags: wpf, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have a WPF app that gets installed via an MSI, generated from a "setup project" in visual studio 2010. I was wondering how I tell the setup project to start the WPF app (primary output) after the installer is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here, using a custom action:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx