# application run on windows startup after installation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have publish my current project. I got the publish folder in my Project's folder. I installed my program and it works perfectly, but I need to know if it is possible that after installation (installer is from the Visual Studio 2012 when you publish the project) the program will start automatically upon windows start up.

Comment: Here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905085/start-wpf-app-after-msi-installation-complete

Comment: Hi Def, thank you so much for giving me that link. But I need to know first before I proceed to follow such long steps, if this will make my application to start automatically UPON WINDOWS Start up? Meaning it will configure my registry to make my application start.

Comment: If you need to run your application upon windows startup- use windows services for this purpose. you should look at Topshelf library. It is win service wrapper

Comment: Hey Def, easy. I don't know what you're trying to say. Sorry, really I'm not a professional in C#/Visual Studio deep stuffs.

Comment: Which installer do you use? InstallShield, WiX, ...? Please tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Hi Andreas, I don't know what kind of installer is this. But this is from the Visual Studio 2012. In my application, I just open its properties and then click PUBLISH, and then a publish folder is generated and there I found the setup.exe

Comment: The "installer" you are using is called [ClickOnce deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

Comment: Guys, it's okay now. But I NEED to know if key.SetValue requires admin rights? I set my program to require admin rights because it will set a value in registry.

Comment: I'll post my installer here later and I'll blog my experiences. http://prettyitgirl.blogspot.com/ :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the installer create a link to your application in the Windows Registry, under the Run or RunOnce registry keys for Windows.

Here is more information about the Run and RunOnce registry keys:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: and how to create a link? like this? var path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true);
key.SetValue("MyApplication", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()); Please? I'm confused with application path stuffs.

Comment: I would use the installer to add the registry key. What technology are you using as your installer? You mentioned that you were using "publish", but to my knowledge, that is for Web apps, not desktop apps, unless I am missing something.

Comment: I'm not using any installer technology like MSI Installer, etc... Because that's not free, right? And I think that would require more effort. Anyway,  I don't know what kind of installer is this. But this is from the Visual Studio 2012. In my application, I just open its properties and then click PUBLISH, and then a publish folder is generated and there I found the setup.exe........ This project is already done, I just need to run it at user's windows start up.

Comment: ok I found a link that has the list of free setup softwares: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-setup-builder.htm

I will try each one and see if there is a feature that will make my program to start automatically at windows start up. But keep me posted please? Then I will mark your answer as answer. Thank you Wolf. lol

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the "publish" method of VS for desktop apps, so I checked it out on my PC. It seems like a simple, bare-bones deployment method, and it doesn't appear to let you customize any registry keys for installation. Are you doing a wide deployment of this app, or just a few? You could edit the registry manually using RegEdt32.exe if it's just a few, or you could look into some of the other installer technologies that give you more options.

Comment: Ok thank you Wolf. One guy said it is called ClickOnce deployment. I think he's right. I don't know what you mean in Wide development or few. I want to distribute my application to other people and let it be known worldwide someday. :) Although it is very very simple. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: hey Wolf. Thank you for your time. I finally found a way!!! A way to compile my Debug folder for installation. <3 Yes!!! ready for production :) :) :) Thanks! I'll post the installer here: http://prettyitgirl.blogspot.com/ later in the afternoon. It's 3:00AM here. Anyway, I NEED to know if key.SetValue requires admin rights? I set my program to require admin rights because it will set a value in registry. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it will require elevated privileges to write to the Windows registry keys.